# How to stop the preventDefault() when write in the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, react-native

I build a simple blog and this blog is have video and comment section I add some of keys to the video in which when click in space the video stop but when I write comment when I click space to make space between the word the space didn't work in the write and the video still play and pause.

How I can prevent or stop this function when I write the comment

The JavaScript file

```
        window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

    function vidCtrl(e){
      const vid = document.querySelector('video')
      const key = e.code;

      if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    vid.currentTime -= 5;
    if (vid.currentTime < 0) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
    vid.currentTime += 5;
    if (vid.currentTime > vid.duration) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'Space') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
    }


  }
    }
```

The comment Form

```
   <form id="myForm" method="post">
  {{ comment_form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
```

Comment: FYI: using `document.activeElement` user must click the video element before they can use the shortcut keys. check Youtube it doesn't require user to click the video before they can use the shortcut

Comment: I am accept the under person as answer because I am using form to write not textarea and it's worked fine, and I tested your answer and didn't worked  and I replaced the text area to form And also didn't work

Comment: `textarea` is for example because I don't know what generated  element for `comment_form.as_p`, it is `<p contentEditable>` ? but nevermind using document.activeElement is also good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check an active element with `document.activeElement`. If the active element is your `vid`, then go on and execute event handlers.

```js
window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

function vidCtrl(e) {
  const vid = document.querySelector('video');
  const key = e.code;

  if (document.activeElement === vid) {
    if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      vid.currentTime -= 5;
      if (vid.currentTime < 0) {
        vid.pause();
        vid.currentTime = 0;
      }
    } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
      vid.currentTime += 5;
      if (vid.currentTime > vid.duration) {
        vid.pause();
        vid.currentTime = 0;
      }
    } else if (key === 'Space') {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
        vid.play();
      } else {
        vid.pause();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check target element using `e.target` then return if current element is your comment box

demo not working here, try on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfgm8nbu/)

```js
window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

function vidCtrl(e) {
  console.log(e.target.localName);
  if(e.target.localName == "textarea");
     return
  
  const vid = document.querySelector('video')
  const key = e.code;
  
  if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    vid.currentTime -= 5;
    if (vid.currentTime < 0) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
    vid.currentTime += 5;
    if (vid.currentTime > vid.duration) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'Space') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<textarea style="width:80%; height:60px"></textarea>
```